# Use Mutual Information Feature Selection For Categorical Feature

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, mutual-information

I have a dataset in which there are Features of both float and object type . I want to apply feature selection On this dataset in such a way that fisrt Find Mutual Information Score of all the features with Target. Then I choose 20 high score feature and do SFFS on them.
So, I use mutual_info_classif in my codes but I get this error:
could not convert string to float
Because of one of my feature (Name=Grade) that is categorical and the unique value of this feature is :A,B,C,D. I have searched for finding the solution and everybody said that in this condition you should use one hot encoding. but I cant understand how to use one hot encoding? because I want to score each feature , not each category of feature. and If for example category=A get high score and category=D get Low score How can I decide to select or not select Grade feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder` to convert your strings to integer values. One hot encoding would be the wrong choice since mutual information can directly work with categorical variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif as MIC
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "grade": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "number": [1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5],
    }
)
target = np.array(["Pass","Pass","Fail","Fail"])

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
df[["grade"]] = enc.fit_transform(df[["grade"]])

MIC(df, target, discrete_features=[True,False])
```

array([0.69314718, 0.        ])

Comment: Thank You , If the data is not ordinal, and is just categorical, can i use label encoder ? @Turamarth

Comment: @nasim_bb yes. Practically speaking both have the same [functionality](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder). It doesn't matter which one you use.